# Proving that a homomorphism is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

The question states... Let $\phi: G \to G$ be a homomorphism with the map $\phi(g)=g^2$. Prove $\phi$ is abelian.

So far I have:

Let $g$ and $h$ be in $G$. Then $\phi(g)=g^2$ and $\phi(h)=h^2$. Since we know it is a homomorphism,

$\phi(gh)=\phi(g)*\phi(h)=g^2*h^2....$

But I don't know how to make a connection that they're abelian. I want to show $\phi(gh)=\phi(hg)$ eventually right?

Comment: What does it mean for a homomorphism to be abelian? You're presumably talking about the group $G$, not the map $\phi$.

Comment: What you actually want to prove that group $G$ is abelian from the given homomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi(gh)=(gh)^2=gh.gh$. By what you said, it is also equal to $g^2.h^2$. So you get $gh.gh=g^2.h^2$. Premultiply both sides by $g^{-1}$ and post multiply both sides by $h^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh! So both are correct! Thus I could set them equal to each other and perform right and left hand cancellation! Thank you!